# Fisher's linear discriminant VS naive bayes

Tags: naive-bayes, fishers-exact-test

i know some basic things about linear classifiers. i prefer two think geometrically about them. and what'll happening if covariance Matrix were different things.

Generally; What's the difference of these Two Algorithm?

Comment: What do you mean saying `if covariance Matrix were different things`? Also, I'd recommend you to search this site for `discriminant analysis fisher bayes` because the topic is not a new one here.

Comment: I mean Drawing The Seperator in diffrent Samples with varietal Cov Matrix.